# PostgreSQL: compress JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with a JSON type column and I have 1 row in the table.
Following request show me result `20761` bytes:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(test_column) FROM test_table;
```

The value from test_column has size `45888` bytes so it means that PostgreSQL compressed this data, but it compressed `45888/20761=~2.1` times. How can I do compression of JSON type more than existing value?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to improve the built-in compression algorithm of Postgres? That's only possible by changing the Postgres source code?

Comment: maybe is there any extensions for Postgres that can do it?

Comment: You can't change the built-in compression algorithm. You might want to have a look in to the extension `zson` which is a dictionary based compression tailored for JSONB: https://github.com/postgrespro/zson

Comment: Are you actually using JSON or JSONB?  If you're using JSON, try JSONB.  There's basically no advantage to using JSON over JSONB.

Comment: @JohnChristopherJones is that really true? In some cases I've found JSONB size to be 130% of the JSON string size. There's also parse and encode time with JSONB. I'm curious how you reconcile these differences but still conclude with "basically no advantage"?

Comment: In many scenarios JSONB could be a better option than JSON though definitely not in all cases, e.g., see https://heapanalytics.com/blog/engineering/when-to-avoid-jsonb-in-a-postgresql-schema (there are many other articles on the topic). I'd consider saying that there is no advantage to be fairly misleading, indeed these are not advantages but disadvantages of JSONB ;-)

Comment: @jso good point, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Changing the type to `jsonb` does *not* make it use less disk space, it might in some cases even use more. Take a look at [ZSON](https://github.com/postgrespro/zson). It is a PostgreSQL extension that compresses the JSON data by creating a lookup table for the most common data, most likely the json-keys, and it claims to be able to save up to half of the needed disk space.